# Phalcon response object is not working

Tags: php, redirect, phalcon

I cannot get the response object to work and I have tried many implementations referenced by the documentation. I don't have an external configuration for the response object, only what is in the code below.

When this code is run an empty page is displayed (there is no view linked with this action). I get no error messages in the browser / apache / php logs either.

I've checked the path to the controllers directory, which is located at:

"__ DIR __ . '/../controllers/'"

My code:

```
public function sendAction()
{
    $this->response->redirect("contact/index");
}
```

If I place the following code at the top of the method, I see the expected page...

```
    echo phpInfo();
    die();
```

I have tried all combinations below:

```
    $this->response->redirect("contact/index");

    // Example shown in Phalcon Docs

    $this->response->redirect("http://en.wikipedia.org", true);
    return $this->response->redirect("http://en.wikipedia.org", true);


    // Should navigate to the base URI

    $this->response->redirect();
    return $this->response->redirect();

    // Creating a new instance of \Phalcon\Http\Response

    $resp = new \Phalcon\Http\Response();
    $resp->redirect("http://en.wikipedia.org", true);
```

I'm really not sure what else to try. I have scoured forums and documentation but haven't found anything that solves my issue.

**Yes this question has been asked before but the answer didn't help!**

I'm running Phalcon 2.0.1 | PHP 5.6.27 | Chrome v.54 | OSX 10.12

My opinion is that the code isn't wrong, but something must not be configured properly. I have tried installing php and Phalcon a couple of times, neither went smoothly and I downloaded a number of required packages and missing elements as I came across them trying to install. I then backed up my data and wiped my hard drive to start fresh, but the problem persists.

Comment: A wild guess, did you try: `$this->response->redirect("contact/index"); return true;`

Comment: And what is url ? With current code ? No return true is not needed. returning response object should work fine. 

First i would try to update phalcon to latest version or 2.0.13.

Comment: @juri, I vaguely remember it being required in an older version of Phalcon :)

Comment: Hi @Timothy, returning true didn't solve it. @:Juri I've added the url to the post, thanks for the help!

Comment: I've added a similar post on forum.phalconphp which also includes information on the configuration files: https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/14667/response-object-not-working#C42419

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Even if the official documentation makes examples like this

```
// Redirect to the default URI
$response->redirect();

// Redirect to the local base URI
$response->redirect("posts/index");

// Redirect to an external URL
$response->redirect("http://en.wikipedia.org", true);

// Redirect specifying the HTTP status code
$response->redirect("http://www.example.com/new-location", true, 301);
```

The only way it worked for me was returning the response send method. I hope it solves your problem too.

```
$this->response->redirect("http://en.wikipedia.org", true, 302);
return $this->response->send();
```